# Simplifying linear inequality constraints.

Tags: inequality, constraint-programming

Suppose i have the following quadratic program, which needs to be solved for y :

$$\min y'Ay + b'y \text{      s.t: } Gy \ge h$$

Where $A$ is a $n$ by $n$ diagonal matrix, $y$ and $b$ are n-dimensional vectors, and $G$ is a $m_G$ by $n$ matrix and $h$ is a $m_G$-dimensional vector.

Is there a way i could convert my inequality constraints into somthing that will look like *box-constraints* on the variables $y_i$, on the form :

$$\forall i, a_i \le y_i \le b_i$$

Note that the only thing i know about $G$ is that $m_G > n$. I am open to use a change of variable and modify $A$ and $b$, but i cant find the way to do it.

**First guess :** I might have to use some kind of *basis* of the affine half-space defined by $Gy>=h$.